# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на сам блок менял цвет только определенный текст

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть кусочек из макета:
[image: ![]

```
Вот мой код: https://codepen.io/idmd/pen/dKdYeq
```

У меня цвет меняется только **при наведении на сами цифры**. А мне нужно чтобы **при наведении на сам блок**, цвет **цифр** менялся. Подскажите как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.block:hover .cifry
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

Raz, dva, tri, chetyre pjat' ...
<span class="cifry">123</span>
Raz, dva, tri, chetyre pjat' ...

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @dmd7 На здоровье. Успехов! Обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответа.